# Cassandra Data Modeling Design

Tags: cassandra

I am fairly new to Cassandra and have been reading a lot over the last month.

I am working on a small use case.

Query: Top X Players based on AmountPlayed in a TimeRange.

So at any given time range i would want to aggreagate players TotalAmountPlayed and derive Top X Players.

I followed the approach of creating UDF (using C*-2.2.0 version) for aggregation of AmountPlayed by a Player.

Below is my Time Series data model i designed for this use case.

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY PlayerRating
(
PlayerNumber int, ===> Unique account number
GameID text, ===> unique machine ID per slot
AmountPlayed double, ===> AmountPlayed by the player
EventTime timestamp, ===> Event generated TimeStamp
PRIMARY KEY ((PlayerNumber, GameID),EventTime)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(EventTime desc);
```

Please let me know if my Data Model design is proper for My Query.

Thank You !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to put all the players for each game into a single partition.

That way you could aggregate all the players with one query instead of making a separate query for each player.  Then you could aggregate the playing time for each player into a map (see an example of how to define the UDF's for that [here](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/05/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html)).

So your table would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE playing_time_by_game (game_id text, event_time int, player_id text, amount_played int, PRIMARY KEY (game_id, event_time));
```

Then create the UDF to total by player_id:

```
CREATE FUNCTION state_group_and_total( state map<text, int>, type text, amount int )
     CALLED ON NULL INPUT
     RETURNS map<text, int>
     LANGUAGE java AS '
     Integer count = (Integer) state.get(type);  if (count == null) count = amount; else count = count + amount; state.put(type, count); return state; ' ;
```

Then create the aggregate function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE group_and_total(text, int) 
     SFUNC state_group_and_total 
     STYPE map<text, int> 
     INITCOND {};
```

Then insert some data:

```
SELECT * from playing_time_by_game ;

 game_id | event_time | amount_played | player_id
---------+------------+---------------+-----------
   game1 |          0 |             8 |   player1
   game1 |          1 |            12 |   player2
   game1 |          5 |             1 |   player2
   game1 |          8 |            50 |   player1
   game2 |          0 |           200 |   player1
```

Now you can aggregate by player_id:

```
SELECT group_and_total(player_id, amount_played) from playing_time_by_game;

 t2.group_and_total(player_id, amount_played)
----------------------------------------------
              {'player1': 258, 'player2': 13}
```

And you can restrict the query to the game partition and time range:

```
SELECT group_and_total(player_id, amount_played) from playing_time_by_game where game_id='game1' and event_time >=0 and event_time <=7;

 t2.group_and_total(player_id, amount_played)
----------------------------------------------
                {'player1': 8, 'player2': 13}
```

You could probably also define a FINALFUNC to sort and keep just the top ten items in the map.  See [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html).